# What is the 'best practice' for installing perl modules on Solaris/OpenSolaris?

Tags: solaris, perl, opensolaris, cpan

I'm currently in the process of writing setup instructions for some software I've written that is implemented as a set of Perl modules. Having done this for various flavours of Linux, I'm now doing the same for Solaris/OpenSolaris (v10 only).

Part of the setup process is to make sure that dependent Perl modules are installed. This has been pretty easy on Linux as the Perl modules I require tend to be within the distro's packaging system (eg `yum install perl-Cache-Cache`).

This is not the case on Solaris so I'm working on setup instructions that use the CPAN module to fetch dependent modules (eg `perl -MCPAN -e 'install Cache::Cache'`). This works ok but there are known problems with modules that require things to be built with a C compiler.

The problem is that the C Makefile generated assumes you're using Sun's compiler and uses command-line options not understood by gcc, which you may be using instead. Consulting teh Internetz has thrown up a number of solutions to this:

- [Install and use Sun's compiler](http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2009/06/19/fixing-cpan-perl-module-installation-issues-opensolaris)
- [Use the `perlgcc` wrapper script](http://www.oreillynet.com/sysadmin/blog/2005/10/perl_options_for_solaris_10.html)
- Edit the makefiles by hand (yuk)

All of these work. My question to those more familiar with Solaris than me is: Is one of these the 'best' or 'most commonly used' method?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at OpenCSW. With pkgutil you have a apt/yum-like way to install the packages you need. We have Perl 5.10.1 and almost 500 Perl modules and we will build more if you need them.

www.opencsw.org